# when you run integration Test, no data will be saved in the database

Tags: java, spring, testing

I'm trying to write an integration test of the service layer. The method of checking the reading of all fields from the database.

```
Entity class
@Getter@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "users", schema = "main")
public class UserEntity {
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    private Long id;
    
    private String name;
}
```

Service

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserEntity create(UserEntity object) {
        return UserRepository.save(object);
    }

    @Override
    public UserEntity get(Long id) {
        return UserRepository.findById(id)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException(USER_NOT_FOUND));        
    }        
}
```

For tests, I use the h2 database, the settings are standard

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS main
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    username: sa
    password: password
```

Integration tests for the service layer

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class UserIntTest {
  
    @Autowired
    private UserService UserService;
    
    @Test
    @Sql({"/getUsers_shouldOk.sql"})
    @Transactional    
    public void getUsers_shouldOk() {
       var result = userService.getAll();
       // I've tried that too
       //var result = userRepository.findAll();

       assertThat(result, notNullValue());
       assertThat(result.size(), is(3));
    }
}
```

File getUsers_shouldOk.sql

```
INSERT INTO `user` (`id`, `name`) VALUES (1, 'user-01');
INSERT INTO `user` (`id`, `name`) VALUES (2, 'user-02');
INSERT INTO `user` (`id`, `name`) VALUES (3, 'user-03');
```

I add three entries to the database using the @Sql annotation on this method. But when reading data from the database, I get an empty list. The sql file getUsers_shouldOk.sql is located in the resources folder. There are no errors when running the test on this file. Why can't I read the data from the database?

It seems that the problem is that I use a scheme, I did not specify it in the original question, now I have corrected the question.
I also had an error in my code, in the getUsers_shouldOk.sql file I also forgot to specify the schema. But I don't understand why I didn't get the error. If I try to access the users table in the terminal, I get an error that there is no such table, but it only works like this

main.users

But when I added the schema to the getUsers_shouldOk.sql file, when I run the test, I now get an error

```
Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of class path resource [getManufactures_shouldOk.sql]: INSERT INTO `main.users` (`id`, `name`) VALUES (1, 'user-01'); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "main.users" not found
```

Comment: exception says about table `users` but sql you sare showing is using `user` table. So which one is it?

Answer (score 1):

@Rollback(false) or @Commit depending on your Spring version.

Comment: Indeed, by default, the transaction will be rolled back. But isn't the transaction rolled back after the method is executed?

Comment: It didn't help. Perhaps there is some kind of hole connected with the scheme. I corrected the question.

Comment: No idea why this is upvoted

Comment: ...the question was changed after the answer.

Answer (score 1):

First, add instructio to create database schema, since you are not doing it by yourself (but it should be by default i think)

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop (convert to yaml if needed)
```

next, decide if your table is going to be `users` as here

```
@Table(name = "users", schema = "main")
```

or `user` as here

```
INSERT INTO `user` (`id`, `name`) VALUES (1, 'user-01');
```

and last thing fyi, `@Transactional` method in test will end up with rolled back transaction (which is good actually as long as you dont want to test some post transaction logic). Reading anything from the db after test will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use H2 DB. which is in-memory database. in spring boot projects under resources folder create schema.sql and add create table statements.
create import.sql add sql queries (create,update,delete).
In Junit fetch data from details give in table.

You can refer: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jpa-test-in-memory-database